# default equality operator C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, equality-operator

In C++20, if we use the default `<=>`, then all the other comparison operators are also added.
Here in the code the class has two integers so to compare there would be user-defined comparison required. But since the equality operator will be generated automatically, I need to know how it will compare the objects. What happens if there is a composite type.

```
#include<compare>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}
    friend strong_ordering operator<=>(const Point&, const Point&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    Point p(2,3), q(2,3);
    
    if(p==q) cout << "same" << endl;
    else cout << "different" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "might be generated"? It compares if all members are equal, no?

Comment: So, does it compare each member?

Comment: Default Comparison Operators - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons   _"...The default operator<=> performs lexicographical comparison by successively comparing the base (left-to-right depth-first) and then non-static member (in declaration order) subobjects of T to compute <=>, recursively expanding array members (in order of increasing subscript), and stopping early when a not-equal result is found, ..."_

Answer (score 3):

All defaulted comparison operators of any kind work the same way. They compare all subobjects (base classes and members), in declaration order, one after the other, until the comparison criteria is determined.

So for equality testing, it tests `Point::x`, then `Point::y`. But it will stop at `x` if `x` were unequal.

Comment: Does this auto overload equality operator compare object size first? Because the built in `==` in the pre 20 standard required that the overall object sizes be checked before iterating through each element, this can show many inequalities without wasting time picking through thousands of elements. Making it inherently different from the `<=>` which must look through the elements to get > or < regardless of the overall size match and so has no efficiency reason to check overall sizes.

Comment: @MaxPower: "*Does this auto overload equality operator compare object size first?*" Comparison operators can only be defaulted if they're comparing the same types. And the same type always has the same "object size". "*Because the built in == in the pre 20 standard required that the overall object sizes be checked before iterating through each element*" There is no "built in == in the pre 20 standard". Standard library containers have their own `==` overloads. Most still do because the default behavior doesn't make sense for complex data structures.